# Datatables sorting varchar

Tags: datatables

I have a SQL query that is pulling back results ordered correctly when I try the query in MSSQL Studio.

I am using Datatables from Datatables.net and everything is working great apart from a sorting issue.  I have some properties in the first column and I would like to order these like this:

```
1
1a
1b
2
3
4a
5
etc
```

However what comes back is something like this:

```
1
10
100
11
11a
```

I have looked though various posts but nothing seems to work and I believe that this must be something I should trigger from the datatables plugin but cannot find anything.

Could someone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Your data contain numbers and characters, so they will be sorted as string by default. You should write your own plugin for sorting your data type. Have a look at [here](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) and [here](http://www.datatables.net/development/sorting)
to see how to write a plugin and how to use it with your table.

Edit: got some time today to work with the datatable stuff. If you still need a solution, here you go:

```
//Sorting plug-in
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    //pre-processing
    "numchar-pre": function(str){
        var patt = /^([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)$/;    //match data like 1a, 2b, 1ab, 100k etc.
        var matches = patt.exec($.trim(str));
        var number = parseInt(matches[1]);     //extract the number part
        var str = matches[2].toLowerCase();    //extract the "character" part and make it case-insensitive
        var dec = 0;
        for (i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        {
         dec += (str.charCodeAt(i)-96)*Math.pow(26, -(i+1));  //deal with the character as a base-26 number
        }
        return number + dec;       //combine the two parts
    },

    //sort ascending
    "numchar-asc": function(a, b){
        return a-b;
    },

    //sort descending
    "numchar-desc": function(a, b){
        return b-a;
    }
});

//Automatic type detection plug-in  
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
   function(sData)
   {
        var patt = /^([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)$/;
        var trimmed = $.trim(sData);
        if (patt.test(trimmed))
        {
            return 'numchar';
        }
        return null;
    }
 );
```

You can use the automatic type detection function to let the data type automatically detected or you can set the data type for the column

`"aoColumns": [{"sType": "numchar"}]`

Comment: That would be good - datatables are great but finding a few limitations now!

Comment: @NickGreen : I've updated my answer with plug-in code which matches the data, transforms and sorts them. I wonder if it also works for you. If you have another solution, can you share it here?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I have placed your code in but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Do I need to call this from anywhere else?

Comment: you just have to place the code in a `<script></script>` tag, after you have included all the related datatables js files. If it doesnt work, try to remove the type auto-detection part and set the type of the column manually as I mentioned. Make sure that all the data in the column have the correct format (1a, 2b etc.). I have tested the code and it worked well.

Comment: Would it make a difference if some data was just numeric? Imagine house numbers so you could have "1" and "1a".

Comment: @NickGreen: if some data was numeric, you just have to change the pattern to `var patt = /^([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]*)$/` in both functions, the pattern will then match 1, 2 etc as well as 1a, 2b etc.