# How to do a custom sorting in datatables?

Tags: sorting, datatables

Is it possible to sort `numeric item` according to its values in a column which contains both `numeric and string items` in datatables?

I tried `columnDefs`:

```
[{ type: 'natural', targets: [0,1] }]
```

But it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps an example of your data?

Comment: You need to have the [**natural**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural) plugin loaded and use `targets: [0,1]` (not `0.1`) if you want to target the first and second column.

Comment: i tried numchar and changes in plugins [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363042/datatables-sorting-varchar. not succeed. want sort according to numeric value like 1
1a
1b
2
3
4a
5
etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, perhaps you just need to see a working example? Here is the values from the other question you are referring to, and the usage of a sorting plugin I once made for exactly this, `any-number` -> https://github.com/davidkonrad/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/any-number.js

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs : [
     { type: 'any-number', targets: [0] }
   ]
})
```

see how it is working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/o53burrf/**
This is how most of the other sorting plugins works as well - if you want to use `natural`, include the source snippet an replace `any-number` with `natural`.